# Remove similarity in jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I tried below code and it works. But I want  to shorten code which is I repeated for 'page-info' child div.

```js
$('.scroll-container').on('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function(event) {
            var delta = Math.max(-1, Math.min(1, (event.originalEvent.wheelDelta || -event.originalEvent.detail)));
            var distance = $('.scroll-items').innerWidth();
            
            $(this).animate({
                scrollLeft: ($(this).scrollLeft() - (delta * distance))
            }, 200);
            event.preventDefault();
        });
        
        $('.page-info').on('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function(event) {
            var delta = Math.max(-1, Math.min(1, (event.originalEvent.wheelDelta || -event.originalEvent.detail)));
            
            $(this).animate({
                scrollTop: ($(this).scrollTop() - (delta * 120))
            },);
            return false;
        });
```

```css
body {overflow: hidden;}
        *{margin: 0; padding: 0;}
        
        .scroll-container {
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            overflow-x: hidden;
        }
        .scroll-items {
            display: flex;
            flex: 0 0 40%;
            height: 100vh;
            font-size: 36px;
            align-items: center;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        .page-info {height: 100%; padding: 15px; overflow: scroll; border: 1px solid yellow;}
        .page-info p {padding: 20px; text-align: justify;}
        .scroll-items {border: 1px solid blue;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="scroll-container">
            
                <div class="scroll-items">
                    <div class="page-info">
                        <p>What is Lorem Ipsum?
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.

Why do we use it?
It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).
                    </div><!--page-info ends-->
                </div>
                
                <div class="scroll-items">1</div>
                <div class="scroll-items">2</div>
                <div class="scroll-items">3</div>
                <div class="scroll-items">4</div>
                <div class="scroll-items">5</div>
                <div class="scroll-items">6</div>
                
        </div>
```

I tried below code and it works. But I want  to shorten code which is I repeated for 'page-info' child div. Please anyone can give me an idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can add same `event` on multiple `classes` and handle your logic by checking the class using `hasClass` -

```
$('.scroll-container, .page-info').on('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var delta = Math.max(-1, Math.min(1, (event.originalEvent.wheelDelta || -event.originalEvent.detail)));
  var isPageInfo = $(this).hasClass("page-info");
  var distance = isPageInfo ? 120 : $('.scroll-items').innerWidth();
  var animateTime = isPageInfo ? 200: 0;

  $(this).animate({
    scrollLeft: ($(this).scrollLeft() - (delta * distance))
  }, animateTime);
});
```

Comment: Your code works for only horizontal scroll and page-info content not scroll vertically. Please see my snippet.